# about UFS allocation on FreeBSD

Tags: filesystems, freebsd

I am wondering what allocation method does UFS use?
I know there are several options: contiguous, linked allocation and indexed allocation.
Which one is for UFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details are in the paper [A Fast File System for UNIX](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~brewer/cs262/FFS.pdf):

> The bit map of available blocks in the cylinder group replaces the traditional file system’s free list.

Answer (score 0):

Your example terms don't coincide with anything I'm familiar with in file systems. The two proper forms of allocations I know of relate to disk space and inodes.

Where disk space is concerned, the two key forms for traditional file systems are extent-based and block-based. UFS is block-based.

Inodes are allocated statically (i.e., at file system creation time) or dynamically. UFS allocates inodes statically.

Does your question refer to some other facet of UFS, perhaps?